# Attempting to create tests in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've got a Spring Boot app using a H2 database that follows a basic structure, i.e. has a few services that get and persist data to the repositories, then has controllers which map the requests and call the services. I've created tests for the repository directly which work fine but now I'm trying to create some tests for the controller, for example for a get request to here it should return this data. But I keep getting null pointer exception and I can't workout how to fix it..
So far it basically looks like this.

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
   
   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @MockBean
   private UserService userService;

   @Test
   public void getUsers() throws Exception {
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users")).andExpect(status().isOk())
   }
}
```

Even this attempt at a basic set up for the tests returns null pointer, along with a few other variations I've tried. I'm new to Spring so I imagine I'm missing something very simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Demo.Controller.UserControllerTest.getUsers(UserControllerTest.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

Comment: Please share the logs

Comment: Made edit, not sure if that helps at all

Comment: can you tell what is at line 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - you're running the JUnit (4 or 5) test. But you don't specify that it should initialize spring's application context.

So if you're with junit 4, add the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
....
```

If you're using junit 5, then it looks slightly different:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
...
```

Another thing to handle is the usage of `UserService`. You should make sure (by placing a breakpoint or something in the contrtoller code) that the reference to the userService is initialized and its exactly the same object as you've defined in the `@MockBean UserService userService`.

Then as @Umesh has mentioned, you need to specify an expectation from that stub. For that use mockito library like you do in regular unit tests:

```
Mockito.when(userService.whateverYouCallFromController(/*parameters if any*/)).thenReturn(... whatever you return there ...);
```

`@MockBean` annotation creates a mock/stub (with the help of mockito) and places it in the application context during the creation of spring applicaiton context. Since you call it in controller's method under test, you should specify what do you expect it to return upon such a call without execution the actual business logic behind.

Last thing - you've mentioned H2 in the question but for WebMvcTests its basically irrelevant - it creates a slice of your beans relevant to the web layer and doesn't even create repositories where you're supposed to call the database.

Comment: Oh right that's a massive help, the first part of it is now working. It's now stuck on the next section. Since the repositories won't even be created and I'm making a call to the service to grab a User from an irrelevant repository, what should I be expecting it to return. For example, Mockito.when(userService.getUserById(1)).thenReturn(?)

Comment: WebMvcTests are required to test the controllers (web layer) stuff like the correctly defined mapping, validations that you might have in controllers, and so forth. If you want to run the whole flow you don't need those. If you're using spring boot, you'll have to use `@SpringBootTest` annotation that kind of mimics the whole app startup (its much heavier as well but loads the whole app)

Answer (score 0):

You have used @MockBean for UserService but you are not stubbing the values of UserService:

Below is a simple stubbing example, you need to stub the method which is being called in userService else null pointer exception will be thrown.

```
 @Test
   public void getUsers() throws Exception {
      when(userService.someMethod()).thenReturn("Hello, Mock");
      this.mockMvc.perform(get("/users")).andExpect(status().isOk())
   }
```